# Working around the "ValidationException: TimeToLive is already disabled" error in terraform for dynamodb

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, terraform

So in my main.tf file, when getting the ValidationException error with terraform/terragrunt, I commented out the following:

```
  #ttl {
  #  attribute_name = "expiration_timestamp"
  #  enabled        = false
  #}
```

1. Will that "unset" the ttl attribute on the corresponding dynamodb table?
2. Does not specifying a ttl attribute mean there's a default expiration time on a row in a dynamodb table or does that mean it will never expire?

Answer (score 1):

1. Removing TTL block will not disable it if it was already enabled. There is an **open issue** for that  on GitHub:

- [tfstate file is showing wrong state when disabling ttl in DynamoDB](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/15154)

2. Yes, if you don't specify TTL in the first place, items **do not expire**.